# Am I misinterpreting formulas from which to derive a conclusion in FOL?

Tags: logic

The two premises and the conclusion are below, together with my interpretations:

P1) ∀s∃t(¬R(s,t) ∧ ¬(s=t)) - For every element s in the domain, there is a t which R doesn't relate to s and that is not s itself. This means all elements in the domain are not related to themselves and there is one element apart from themselves that they are not related to.

P2) ∀s∃tR(s,t) - for all elements s, there exists a t such that R relates s to t.

The conclusion is

C) ⊢ ∃s¬R(s,s) - There exists an element that R does not relate to itself.

Based on my interpretation above, I think the following demonstrates this:

Domain:0,1,2

R(*,*):<0,1>,<1,0>,<2,0>

I think that based on my interpretation, I think this is correct but I keep getting a response that I am wrong?

Or am I meant to provide a counter example?

Comment: Counterexample: say there are only 2 elements a and b, and R(a,a) and R(b,b) and no other relations hold. Premises are true, conclusion is false.

Comment: Your "This means all elements in the domain are not related to themselves" is incorrect. The first sentence says that for each element in the domain there is at least one other that is not R-related. Remember ∃ is *at least one* so this does not rule out an element being R-related to itself as well.

Comment: @Bumble So, the first part is "All elements x have at least one other element y that they are not related and it is not the case that the element it is not related to is itself" Thank you

Comment: @causative So since there is nothing barring it from relating to itself, it does not follow that there must exist one not relating to itself. Thank you

Comment: Aside from the above, you cannot demonstrate entailment ⊢ by an example, it would need a derivation in FOL instead. In this case, no such derivation exists because there is a counterexample, as causative pointed out. So your assignment likely did mean for you to produce a counterexample.

Comment: P1 is just "All elements have at least one other element that they are not related to". It does not exclude that other element being related to itself. The ¬(s=t) term is there to enforce the 'other'. Without it, ∀s∃t(¬R(s,t)) would mean that for every element s there is a non-R-related t, but it might be that t=s and s is not R-related to itself.